# How to do a loop that starts at '0'

Tags: r

I have tried to do this function:

```
P<- numeric()
for(x in 1:5) {
  P[x] <- (2*x)+3
}
P
```

and the result is OK -- # [1]  5  7  9 11 13

I'd like to start in x=0, but there is not result by x=0

```
P<- numeric()
for(x in 0:5) {
  P[x] <- (2*x)+3
}
P
# [1]  5  7  9 11 13
```

Is there any way to do it?
Thanks

Comment: Arrays in R start with index 1, not index zero. So make sure your index is in range. Try `P<- numeric(); for(x in 0:5) {P[x+1] <- (2*x)+3}; P`. Or even better without the loop: `x <- 0:5; P <- (2*x)+3`

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly. Actually I wanted the loop because I wanted to calculate a Poisson distribution with parameter lambda=4 on a set of values (from 0 to 20) starting at 0.      P<- numeric(); lambda=4;    for(i in 0:20) { P[i+1] <- exp(-lambda)*(lambda^i) /factorial(i) };  P i<- 0:(length(P)-1);  plot(i, P,); lines(i,P) # And the result (P) is the same as: dpois(0:20, 4)

Comment: Can you explain me why the formula is P[i+1] ?
Intuitively it would look like P[i-1], but I know little about programming.... Thank you very much in any case

Comment: Well, if `x=0` and you need to set `P[1]=` then you need to do `P[x+1]`. But as you already pointed out, you can get the same result with `P <- dpois(0:20,4)`. It's pretty rare that you have to explicitly loop in R.